# ASP.Net code first project The wait operation timed out

Tags: sql, asp.net, azure

I never thought publishing a website could be so hard. After all the trouble it finally published without errors. However when i run it and trying to use db it times out.

```
    Server Error in '/' Application.

    The wait operation timed out
[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out]

[SqlException (0x80131904): Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +2440374
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5765244
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +285
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +4169
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) +948
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry) +286
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +286
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<NonQuery>b__0(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c) +10
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +72
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +356
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<CreateDatabaseFromScript>b__19(DbConnection conn) +119
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass33.<UsingConnection>b__32() +443
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0() +10
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +189
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation) +78
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +175
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +557
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.CreateDatabaseFromScript(Nullable`1 commandTimeout, DbConnection sqlConnection, String createDatabaseScript) +86
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection) +164
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection) +76
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateDatabase() +132
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DatabaseCreator.Create(DbConnection connection) +119
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase) +142
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration) +78
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(InternalContext internalContext, Func`3 createMigrator, ObjectContext objectContext) +89
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CreateDatabase(ObjectContext objectContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) +116
   System.Data.Entity.Database.Create(DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) +218
   System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseAlways`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) +93
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.<CreateInitializationAction>b__e() +76
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +60
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() +357
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext c) +7
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input) +110
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action) +198
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase() +73
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +28
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +53
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator() +15
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator() +53
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +375
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
   PhClub.Controllers.MediasController.Index() +21
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +169
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +228
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9765901
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

After reading relevant posts, i figured out that i could set command timeout for at least 120, as in my connection string it set so. I have an EventContext in project and i tried to use this command like so:

```
this.context.CommandTimeout = 120;
EventContext.context.CommandTimeout = 120;
EventContext.CommandTimeout = 120;
```

none of them worked. 
here is the connection string i use

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="PhClub" connectionString="Server=tcp:*****.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=******;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=Login;Password=*****;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=120" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-PhClub-20170304023453.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-PhClub-20170304023453;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

But what causing timeout? how to figure it out? Could you please give an advise of how i fix it

---

UPDATE

i tried to setup CommandTimeout in a few ways. 
added this to Configuration.cs

```
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 160; // or any other length of time in seconds
    /*Any other properties to be modified in the command will come here*/
    SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Also tried to add it to Web.config to:

```
  <system.web>
    <sessionState timeout ="200" mode = "InProc"/>
<system.web/>
```

together with this code in `Global.asax.cs`

```
void session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session.Timeout = 200;       
}
```

but nothing changed a result. It takes approx 40 seconds to timeout 
It works perfect locally. Perhaps there is something wrong with migration?

UPDATE 2

Perhaps my web.config is not properly prepared for migration? Could anyone have a look on it please?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>

    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
  <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --></configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="PhClub" connectionString="Server=tcp:phclub.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=*****;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=******;Password=******;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=120" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-PhClub-20170304023453.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-PhClub-20170304023453;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState timeout ="200" mode = "InProc"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <authentication mode="None"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30AD4FE6B2A6AEED" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0"/>
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Update 3

Looks like problem is with database creation during publishing. I updated ....init.cs file and added two of the tables creation as well as adding them to down. However that is not enough to fix the problem, any suggestions?

```
namespace PhClub.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    public partial class init : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.AspNetRoles",
                c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                        Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 256),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
                .Index(t => t.Name, unique: true, name: "RoleNameIndex");

            CreateTable(
                "dbo.AspNetUserRoles",
                c => new
                    {
                        UserId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                        RoleId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.UserId, t.RoleId })
                .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetRoles", t => t.RoleId, cascadeDelete: true)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.UserId, cascadeDelete: true)
                .Index(t => t.UserId)
                .Index(t => t.RoleId);

            CreateTable(
                "dbo.AspNetUsers",
                c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                        Email = c.String(maxLength: 256),
                        EmailConfirmed = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                        PasswordHash = c.String(),
                        SecurityStamp = c.String(),
                        PhoneNumber = c.String(),
                        PhoneNumberConfirmed = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                        TwoFactorEnabled = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                        LockoutEndDateUtc = c.DateTime(),
                        LockoutEnabled = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                        AccessFailedCount = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        UserName = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 256),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
                .Index(t => t.UserName, unique: true, name: "UserNameIndex");

            CreateTable(
                "dbo.AspNetUserClaims",
                c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        UserId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                        ClaimType = c.String(),
                        ClaimValue = c.String(),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.UserId, cascadeDelete: true)
                .Index(t => t.UserId);

            CreateTable(
                "dbo.AspNetUserLogins",
                c => new
                    {
                        LoginProvider = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                        ProviderKey = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                        UserId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.LoginProvider, t.ProviderKey, t.UserId })
                .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.UserId, cascadeDelete: true)
                .Index(t => t.UserId);

            CreateTable (
                 "dbo.Events",
                 c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        Title = c.String(),
                        Date = c.String(),
                        DayOfEvent = c.String(),
                        Location = c.String(),
                        Responsible = c.String(),
                        Description = c.String(),
                        Keywords = c.String(),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

                CreateTable(
                     "dbo.Medias",
                     c => new
                     {
                         Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                         title = c.String(),
                         description = c.String(),
                         body = c.String(),
                         ImagePath = c.String(),
                         VideoLink = c.String(),
                         Source = c.String(),
                         tags = c.String(),
                         TagsEnum = c.String(),
                         NewsDate = c.String(),
                     })
                    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUserRoles", "UserId", "dbo.AspNetUsers");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUserLogins", "UserId", "dbo.AspNetUsers");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUserClaims", "UserId", "dbo.AspNetUsers");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUserRoles", "RoleId", "dbo.AspNetRoles");
            DropIndex("dbo.AspNetUserLogins", new[] { "UserId" });
            DropIndex("dbo.AspNetUserClaims", new[] { "UserId" });
            DropIndex("dbo.AspNetUsers", "UserNameIndex");
            DropIndex("dbo.AspNetUserRoles", new[] { "RoleId" });
            DropIndex("dbo.AspNetUserRoles", new[] { "UserId" });
            DropIndex("dbo.AspNetRoles", "RoleNameIndex");
            DropTable("dbo.AspNetUserLogins");
            DropTable("dbo.AspNetUserClaims");
            DropTable("dbo.AspNetUsers");
            DropTable("dbo.AspNetUserRoles");
            DropTable("dbo.AspNetRoles");
            DropTable("dbo.Events");
            DropTable("dbo.Medias");
        }
    }
}
```

Update 4
Here is the github link to this project. 
`https://github.com/x00105893/PHClub/tree/test` managed to save it on to Test branch. Would appreciate All of your help guys. Github pages now available

Comment: looks to be your code in your MVC controller that seems to be creating a database, when usually your visual studio should be set up to publish your database, or at least publish the design changes / Tables for that database.   Rather than a database been created, and populated on first run

Comment: well, i used code first approach. Is that what you are talking about? Any advise of how to fix it?

Comment: yeah but if you look at the chain   in your error stack, from bottom up.   you can see the host start, channels up, calls processes to create the database etc all the way up to you getting the SQL timeout.    Your code has c=some long running SQL task. System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.CreateDatabaseFromScript    looks to be the issue here

Comment: basically, your check databse exist, returns false, because the database doesent exist.  it is then going off on a tangent,  trying to create the database and timing out

Comment: So extending a timeout should really fix this problem, right?

Comment: I have EF v6. Command for that is - this.context.Database.CommandTimeout = 180; However i think im doing something wrong - it says syntax is wrong. Where do i insert this command exactly?

Comment: I tried to sort this out with increasing timeout in configuration.cs like this         public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
            CommandTimeout = Int32.MaxValue;
        } but it still working exactly the same way, looking for help

Comment: I dont use entity framework, but I would right click on project --> properties and on the build release tab I am sure there is tick boxes there to say publish database, also visual studio now has tools to release to azure with all the controls to hook up to azure cloud SQL etc.   think this would be a better avenue than,  I want my code to do it all on launch

Comment: Ticking that option does not solve the issue.